# iPhone Core Location CLLocationManager update rate

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

Can you set up a constant time update rate for CLLocationManager to force it update locations like every 10 seconds continuously? I know the usage of the distance filter but what if something went wrong and the location is not updated? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to control the update rate. You can set a timer, then turn off the updates until the timer ends. This is the usual thing to do to avoid using too much power.

If there's a problem, you will be informed by the delegate method `locationManager:didFailWithError:`

Here's a good post which shows how to filter bad CoreLocation readings:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-bad-corelocation-data/

Comment: I think it is critical to point out here that the timer approach will fail if your app is backgrounded.  You can use a timer to enable and disable your location updates to preserve battery life, but 10 seconds after you call `stopUpdatingLocation` your application is going to be put to sleep by `iOS`, shutting down your timer and preventing the location updates from ever starting again.